# Mint 13 does nothing when laptop lid is closed

Tags: laptop, gnome, linux-mint

I have a laptop running Mint 13.

I have it hooked up to a 30" monitor and have no use for the laptop being open, so I put it on a shelf and close it.  When I do that, the monitor goes blank.  The power manager does not have an option for doing nothing when the lid is closed.  The options are "Blank Screen", "Suspend", and "Shutdown".

Is there a way to make the laptop not go to a blank screen when the lid is closed?

Comment: It sounds the simplest solution would not to fully close the laptop case.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah.  I was looking for a better solution than that.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on a Dell Inspiron 1501 with Linux Mint 13 Mate 32bit.

- Open Configuration Editor (`mateconf-editor`)
- Goto: `apps/mate-power-manager/buttons`
- Change `lid-ac` from "blank" to "nothing"
- Open up Screensaver Preferences / Power Management at the bottom.
- Click make as default (Make sure "When laptop lid is closed" to "do nothing")

Comment: I tried this.  it allows the "Do Nothing" option to show up in the menu, but it still blanks the screen when the lid is closed.

Comment: works on HP-5330m as well ...thx

Comment: I still didn't get the "Do Nothing" option in the screensaver->power management settings. When I close the lid, the external monitor switches off; but waggle the mouse/press any key and it comes back again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by design of the Lid close event handling script of Mint 13. For whatever ('*') state, the instructions execute a 'screenBlank' instruction set. It's clear that it's an assumption they had taken for granted. The following is just a workaround.

**Note**: You might have to use `sudo` or be root to perform this.

Open the file `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`
There find the line `. /usr/share/acpi-support/screenblank`
Comment that out with putting `#` before it.
The issue should be resolved